# Android not able to save data to firebase and localstorage not working

Tags: ionic-framework

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','ngCordova','forceng'])
// LocalStorage
.controller('warehouseCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'reservationService', 
function ($scope, $stateParams, reservationService) {
$scope.warehouse =[];

// list all data from Reservation.json
   reservationService.all().then(function(warehouseArray){
    for (var i = 0; i <warehouseArray.length; i++){
     p={"warehouse":warehouseArray[i].warehouse,
    "Price":warehouseArray[i].Price
  };
  $scope.warehouse.push(p);
   }
 })
 }])


// Reservation submit button
.controller('submitCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams',       '$http','fireBaseService' ,'$localStorage',
function($scope, $stateParams, $http, fireBaseService, $localStorage){
$scope.reservation = {"name": null, "ic": null, "email":null, "phone":null,   "address":null, "warehouse":null, "startDate": new Date(), "endDate": new Date, "remark":null};

$scope.submit = function(){
console.log($scope.reservation.name, $scope.reservation.ic,         $scope.reservation.email, $scope.reservation.phone, $scope.reservation.address, $scope.reservation.warehouse, $scope.reservation.startDate, $scope.reservation.endDate, $scope.reservation.remark);

 fireBaseService.signinUser();
 fireBaseService.save($scope.reservation.name, $scope.reservation.ic,   $scope.reservation.email , $scope.reservation.phone, $scope.reservation.address, $scope.reservation.warehouse, $scope.reservation.startDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US"), $scope.reservation.endDate.toLocaleDateString("en-US"), $scope.reservation.remark);

  $scope.reservation = {"name": null, "ic": null, "email":null, "phone":null, "address":null, "warehouse":null, "startDate": new Date(), "endDate": new Date, "remark":null};


 }
}
])
```

services.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['ngStorage'])

// Reservation Service
.factory('reservationService', ['$http',
function($http) {
var reservation = [];

return {
    all: function(){
        return $http.get('Reservation.json').then(function(response){
            reservation = response.data;
            return reservation;
        });
    },

}
}])

//firebase service
 .factory('fireBaseService', [ '$localStorage',
 function($localStorage){
 var config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyA41FxVS8TFpO_s5aIXFhmX5s9Pz88z5Wc",
authDomain: "emob-823c4.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://emob-823c4.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "emob-823c4.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "1092245519317"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

 // Get a reference to the database service
 var database = firebase.database();

 $storage = $localStorage.$default({
firebaseArray: []
 });
  return{
   createUser: function(){
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
 // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  console.log(error.code, error.message);
 });
  },
   signinUser: function(){
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword('xxx@gmal.com', '123').catch(function(error) {
   // Handle Errors here.
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;
 console.log(error.code, error.message);

});
 },
 signoutUser: function(){
 firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
 console.log('Sign out successful');
 },     function(error) {
  console.log(error);
 });
  },

   save: function(name, ic, email , phone, address, warehouse, startDate, endDate, remark){
   firebase.database().ref('registration/' + ic).set({
   name: name,
   ic: ic,
   email: email,
phone: phone,
address: address,
warehouse: warehouse,
startDate: startDate,
endDate: endDate,
remark: remark
  });
  }

   }
 }])

;
```

tab-reservation.html

```
   <!--<div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
                <img src="img/register.png">
                <h2>Customer Reservation/ Booking</h2>
                <p>Application for to make a reservation or advancement booking for customers.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-image">
        <p>Reservation/Booking Form</p>

            <form class="reservation">
                <div class="list list-inset">

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon  ion-ios-personadd placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.name" placeholder="Name">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-infinite placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.ic" placeholder="IC/Passport Number">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-email placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="email" ng-model="reservation.email" placeholder="Email">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-iphone placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-location placeholder-icon"></i>  
                        <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.address" placeholder="Address" />
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-home placeholder-icon"></i>
                        <select ng-model="reservation.warehouse" ng-controller="warehouseCtrl" ng-options="w.warehouse as w.warehouse for w in warehouse" />
                    </label>
                    <br>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar placeholder-icon"></i>  
                        <input type="date" ng-model="reservation.startDate" placeholder="Warehouse Booking Start Date" />
                    </label>



                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

        <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#">
        <i class="icon ion-music-note"></i>
        Start listening
        </a>

    </div>-->







    <div class="list card">

    <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="img/register.png">
             <h2>Customer Reservation/ Booking</h2>
             <p>Application for to make a reservation or advancement booking for customers.</p>
    </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
            <p>Reservation/Booking Form</p>


            <form class="reservation" ng-controller="submitCtrl">
             <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon  ion-ios-personadd placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.name" placeholder="Name">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-infinite placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.ic" placeholder="IC/Passport Number">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-email placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="email" ng-model="reservation.email" placeholder="Email">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-iphone placeholder-icon"></i>  <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-location placeholder-icon"></i>  
                        <input type="text" ng-model="reservation.address" placeholder="Address" />
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-android-home placeholder-icon"></i>
                        <select ng-model="reservation.warehouse" ng-controller="warehouseCtrl" ng-options="w.warehouse as w.warehouse for w in warehouse"><option value="" disabled selected>Select your warehouse option</option></select>
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">

                        <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar placeholder-icon"></i>  
                        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="reservation.startDate" placeholder="Warehouse Booking Start Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')"/>-->
                        <input type="date" ng-model="reservation.startDate" placeholder="Warehouse Booking Start Date" />
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-calendar-outline placeholder-icon"></i>  
                        <!--<input type="text" ng-model="reservation.endDate" placeholder="Warehouse Booking End Date" onfocus="(this.type='date')"/>-->
                        <input type="date" ng-model="reservation.endDate" placeholder="Warehouse Booking End Date"/>
                    </label>

                    <label class="item item-input">
                        <i class="icon ion-checkmark-circled placeholder-icon"></i>  
                        <textarea ng-model="reservation.remark" placeholder="Any additional remarks..." rows="5"></textarea>
                    </label>

                     <!--<a ui-sref="tab-main" class="button button-positive button-block" ng-controller="submitCtrl" ng-click="submit()">Submit</a>-->
                     <a class="button button-positive button-block"  ng-click="submit()">Submit</a>
            </form>
        </div>

 </div>


 </ion-view>
```

I managed to insert new data into the firebase through my PC web browser however, once I run it on my android devices i could not retrieve my local storage data and could not insert any data into the firebase at all. Thanks You

Comment: Can you update tab-reservation.html to show the Content Security Policy tag?

Comment: What do you mean by showing the content Security policy tag?

Comment: It's a meta tag, it gives the device permissions to do things.  Now, it's probably not the problem (at least not with the local storage part), but I usually check it first any time an app isn't working right, it's caused me hours of troubleshooting for a stupid tag.